# Restore Facebook Session with a token from Shared preferences that has been revoked

Tags: android, facebook, session

I'm integrating Facebook SDK 3.0 in my android app.

Let's imagine that the user opened a Session in the android device. If using the default token strategy the token will be persisted in SharedPreferences.

Then, the user revokes the token in the web or in the Facebook app.

Next, let's imagine that I create a new Session and set it as active (this is what UiLifecycleHelper is there is no active Session.

Next I open the session with:

```
Session.openActiveSession(this, true, mCallback);
```

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Session#openActiveSessionFromCache(Context)

> Create a new Session, and if a token cache is available, open the
>   Session and make it active without any user interaction.

So, with this flow, we will open a Session with a token that is actually revoked...

Is this true? Am I missing something?
How could I treat this? If I try to open another new Session, the same invalid token will be used again...

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that you can clear the token with:

[Session#closeAndClearTokenInformation();](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/Session#closeAndClearTokenInformation%28%29)

So, it seems that what the developers are expected to do is to open the Session with Session.openActiveSession(). If there is a cached token in SharedPreferences and it works, perfect. 
If the token is revoked we won't know it until we receive an auth error when calling the Facebook API. If this happens, you clear the token and re-authenticate again.

Comment: See also the error handling tactics doc - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/